# Can the word Spill be used with a subject?

Tags: word-usage

When you use the word **spill** to convey how someone spilled coffee or something. There's always a subject. If someone said "Don't put the cup there. The coffee could **spill**.", instead of "Don't put the cup there, you could **spill** it.", would it be grammatically incorrect?

Comment: You mean direct object? Yes.

Comment: Spill is both transitive and intransitive, yes

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically incorrect? @Andrew

Comment: @SoumyaGhosh  If you look up "spill" [in a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/spill) you can see it is both transitive and intransitive, meaning you can have someone doing the *spilling*, or not.  Either is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. As Andrew commented, "spill" is both a transitive and intransitive verb. Both "spill the coffee" and "the coffee spilled" are equally acceptable.